# javascript behaves differently in different browsers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, safari, cross-browser

I am working on a project which need to deal with a lot of "dates". I notice that sometimes javascript behaves differently in different browsers:

code:

```
new Date("Mar 30, 2017".replace(',', '').replace(/ /g, '/'))
```

I know I don't need to use `replace` to create date, but this code gives me interesting different result from Chrome and Safari.

While I run:

```
"Mar 30, 2017".replace(',', '').replace(/ /g, '/')
```

Both Chrome and Safari will gives me: `"Mar/30/2017"`. But when I try to turn the result into a `Date` object, the interesting result will be:

```
Chrome: Thu Mar 30 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)
Firefox: Date 2017-03-30T07:00:00.000Z
Safari: Invalid Date
```

I have already checked Javascript version of both browsers, and they are using the same version (1.7). Can anyone explain why Chrome behaves differently than Safari in this regard?

**UPDATE**
I know `"Mar/30/2017"` is not a valid Date format. But my question is **why javascript behaves differently in different browsers**. For those answers complaining about my Date format. Please read the question before answer it. I will take @Felix Kling 's answer, and thanks for all answers all the same.

Comment: Yes, if you pass a non-standard date format to `new Date()` then you get varying results. Only pass [standard formats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) or avoid passing a string altogether if possible.

Comment: Safari's JS implementation may just not be able to understand it, why do you need to create a date as "Mar/30/2017" the first way should work fine [w3 date docs](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Comment: Well, because `"Mar/30/2017"` is not a valid date format according to any specification that I know of. Browsers may interpret it any way they want, or not at all, as you can observe here.

Comment: My question was "Why javascript behaves differently in different browsers", and I said "I know I don't need to use replace to create date". This code is from my friend, and I just think it is interesting to ask. For whoever down vote my question, I really don't understand why? And thanks for your answers anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can anyone explain why Chrome behaves differently than Safari in this regard?

The [specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-date.parse) says that handling unknown date formats is implementation dependent:

> [...]  The String may be interpreted as a local time, a UTC time, or a time in some other time zone, depending on the contents of the String. The function first attempts to parse the format of the String according to the rules (including extended years) called out in Date Time String Format ([20.3.1.16](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-date-time-string-format)). If the String does not conform to that format the function may fall back to any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats. [...]

Safari and Chrome use different JavaScript engines and therefore their behavior can (and do) differ in this case.